# CSS Design seems "off" - React ES6 - Material UI

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui, material-react-table

[image]

I've been using mui/material packages to develop my React Es6 JS Web Application. I was using MUI Data table - https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/ it worked fine.

During development I found out that the Material React Table Library might be better hence decided to try it. https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/examples/editing-crud.

Not sure why the look and feel of the table is different (identified with a '?' in the shared image)

Any possible reasons why it could make it look like that?

Comment: It looks like your stylesheets need rebuilding - or it's possible that your project is mixing styles from different libraries together and they're both trying to style the same elements.